# MySQL Update Table WHERE column in another is

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL and I would like to update a column in one of them to match values from another.

The tables each have a customer and part number column.

```
Table 1:
Customer_Name | Part_Number | Demand | Allocation

Table 2:
Customer_Name | Part_Number | Demand
```

I want to update table 1 to add table 2 demand to the allocation figure in table 1, if the part number and customer both exist in table 2.

A query I have attempted so far:

```
UPDATE `Packing_Dispatch` SET Allocation = `Packing_Allocation`.Demand WHERE
        Customer_Name = `Packing_Allocation`.Customer_Name AND Part_Number = `Packing_Allocation`.Part_Number
```

How can I do this?

Comment: mean you need to update the values on both tables?

Comment: No only update table 1. Lookup the part number and customer in table 2 then copy the demand found to table 1. If that makes sense.

Comment: try with joins eg: update a set col1=1 from table1 a join table2 b on b.id=a.id where add the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
UPDATE `Packing_Dispatch` 
Join `Packing_Allocation`
SET Allocation = `Packing_Allocation`.Demand 
WHERE Customer_Name = `Packing_Allocation`.Customer_Name AND Part_Number = `Packing_Allocation`.Part_Number
```